# sql insert not work c# querybuilder

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a serious problem in connecting to SQL Server 2008 R2 from C# since I have changed some SQL Server settings. Now I cannot connect to SQL Server through the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        kamiDataSetTableAdapters.kami2TableAdapter kap = new     WindowsFormsApplication1.kamiDataSetTableAdapters.kami2TableAdapter();

        decimal a = Convert.ToDecimal( "11.2");
        int b = 11;

        kap.Insert(Convert.ToDecimal("11.2"), b, Convert.ToDecimal("11.2"),  Convert.ToDecimal("11.2"));
    }
}
```

}

(the table has four decimal and one int columns)

However I can connect and insert or select fields by querybuilder gui. Unfortunately I can't upload image because of low reputation.

And the error is

> *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection  to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it.)*

Would you please guide me, my boss is angry!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is your connection string? Are you sure SQL Server is running and configured to accept remote connections? The error message seems pretty clear on what is going wrong...

Comment: It sounds like the SQL Server instance ins't allowing remote connections, that would be the first thing I would check. See if you can TelNet to the SQL Server instance on port 1433.

Comment: yeah sql is running cause I can connect and execute command via querybuilder.!

Comment: Could you please tell me more about "TelNet to the SQL Server instance on port 1433"!?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what settings you changed, it's going to be tough to tell exactly other than it's a connection issue.  You'll want to start with your application's connection strings; as it sounds like you could be connecting using a different one.

I'm assuming remote connections is probably not it; cause you can connect.

If you changed authentication settings or database permissions, you'll need to make sure that whatever account your application connects under has the proper permissions.

Comment: I really don't remember which setting I have manipulated. I have just followed some topic and used that command for enabling sql authenticating.

Comment: would you please explain more about proper permission which you have mentioned in details?

Comment: I think I have permission to connect to sql because querybuilder (defalut gui) is connected and executed properly. but problem is just with adapters.

Answer (score 0):

two possibilities

1/if you use a sql authentication:
make a sqlconnection and try to open a connection with your user and password
if it works change your user password on your connectionstring

if you use a windows authentication:
you set your connection string with Trusted_Connection and check if it works

2/make sure to specify the good sql server instance (servername\serverinstance)

Comment: 1) I have done it using sqlconnection but "conn.open();" encounters the same error message. 2)I specify the instance with dot, I mean the the same server. Does it matters?

Comment: it isn't with dot but slash like this (windows authentication): Server=myServerName\theInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;